# Flutter App not working after deploying Serverpod on Aws

Tags: flutter, dart, serverpod

I have serverpod project it working fine on local host , I can use Crud but after deploying on aws , server still working shows "ok" message but flutter app not working .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Without any logs or additional information, it's hard to diagnose your exact problem.*

My best bet would be that you still have the `localhost` url in your `Client()` call.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , I forgot to remove port number in url , now it's working , thanks again